# AngularJS - Can a successful promise return null data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

Just wondering, I'm writing test cases and haven't been able to find a definitive answer as to whether null can be returned in an angularJS promise (rather than an object called null )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, just like synchronous code a promise can fulfill with whatever you want it to.

```
//example with Bluebird
Promise.try(function(){
    return null;
}).then(function(result){
    alert(result === null); // true
});
```

A promise can also reject with null, but it generally shouldn't since you should always reject with errors.

In Angular, using $q the simplest example is something like `$q.when(null)` which creates a promise fulfilled with the value `null` explicitly.

Comment: It's also always possible to check such things in the A+ spec: http://promises-aplus.github.io/promises-spec/

Comment: Thanks but I was under the impression that AngularJS does not fully implement the spec at this moment in time?

Comment: @LinuxN00b it does. It doesn't include the entire Q feature set but it's definitely Promises/A+ complaint :)

Comment: (Note, anything you want to _except_ another promise, as it will unwrap that promise since promises unwrap recursively)